# MS Access - Dynamic Crosstab Query - VBA for Totals Row that provides Column totals

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have built a dynamic crosstab query where the user selects options from multiple combo boxes and then I use VBA to update the SQL for the cross tab query. It is then, in turn, displayed on a subform. My question is basically how can I programmatically (VBA or SQL, don't really care either way) add a totals row that calculates the average of each column. I know how to do this manually, but since the number of columns and column headings are not set, this is impractical. I would basically like to automatically set a totals row at the bottom for the average of each column regardless of the number of columns or column headers. An example of a potential case is shown below with the user inputs on top.

```
 Group: A               
 Team:    All               
 Start Date:    1/1/2014                
 End Date:  5/31/2014               
 Query Type:    Monthly 

 Name           2014-Jan    2014-Feb    2014-Mar    2014-Apr    2014-May
 John Doe1         1            2         3           4            5
 John Doe2         2            2         2           2            2
 John Doe3         1            5         9          13           17
 John Doe4         2           10        18          26           34
 John Doe5         1            8        15          22           29
 John Doe6         2           12        22          32           42
 John Doe7         1           15        29          43           57
 John Doe8         2           14        26          38           50
 John Doe9         1           12        23          34           45
```

---

```
 Total (Avg):     1.44        8.89     16.33        23.78       31.22
```

I am trying the generate the bottom "Totals" row programmatically without knowing the column count ahead of time and without manually inserting totals via the ribbon.

Comment: You should be able to build another query using the crosstab query to get the averages and then do a union to join them. Can you show your crosstab SQL? It must be parameterized already

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pivot table on a simple select query.

Comment: an example would be useful

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the crosstab query do that for you?

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465B89C-2FF2-4CC8-BA60-2CD8484667E8

http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftAccess/query/crosstab-report/index.html

Although crosstab queries are somewhat limited in their power, you can certainly create another query to do a basic average of the crosstab query you just created.